How far does a for loop go does it matter or not for its time complexity?
I am currently wondering if the complexity of a for loop is affected by how far that loop goes. Two nested for's can be written as a single for that goes from 0 to n*n and would still do n*n  iterations for all possible input sizes, that satisfies the time complexity assumption, so it should be O(n^ 2), but then I found this example in some forums:
   n*=n 
   for(let i=0; i<=n;i++){
   //Some
   }

where they explain that the instruction n*=n is O(1) so the complexity will be decided by the cycle for(let i=0; i<=n;i++) so the total complexity of that cycle would be t (n)=O(1)+O(n)=O(n). Is the latter true or is it O(n^2)? Does it matter or not how far a cycle goes for its time complexity?

@hff1 But the instruction n*=n updated n with n^2.

It's very bad form to change $n$ in the computation, so that you don't know whether to express complexity in terms of the original $n$ or the new $n$.

How "far" a for loop goes, i.e. the number of iterations a for loop does, absolutely affects the time complexity of the algorithm. If you have a for loop that does a constant-time operation and the for loop does $f(n)$ iterations for some function $f$, then the complexity of the algorithm will be $O(f(n))$.
However, when we say $O(f(n))$ for some function $f$, we assume that the variable $n$ is a parameter to the algorithm which does not change value. If $n$ is a variable which changes value during the algorithm, as it does in this algorithm because of the n *= n line, then saying the algorithm is $O(n)$ or that the algorithm is $O(n^2)$ does not make sense because it is not clear which value of $n$ you are talking about.
Instead, to make the discussion more clear, let's say $n_b$ is the value of $n$ before n *= n and $n_a$ is the value of $n$ after n *= n. Using these constants, we see that the operation n *= n is constant-time, so $O(1)$, and then the for loop is doing $n_a$ iterations. Ergo, the time complexity is $O(1)+O(n_a)=O(n_a)$.
However, if we want to put the complexity in terms of $n_b$, then we notice that the line of code n *= n means that $n_a=n_b^2$. Therefore, the time complexity is $O(n_a)=O(n_b^2)$. Thus, if you view the algorithm in terms of $n_b$, then the algorithm is quadratic, but if you view the algorithm in terms of $n_a$, then the algorithm is linear.

Can you recommend a book on algorithms where this initial part is explained well to understand the complexity, most of the ones I have, such as H. Cormen's Introduction to Algorithms, do not deal much with these examples of for cycles, apparently they take it as something trivial
